# Hibernate 6.x org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityKey consumes a lot of memory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

We have just migrated our application to Springboot 3.x, Spring Data JPA 3.1.x & Hibernate 6.1.7 Final.

Immediately we observed heap memory spike as we deployed same code without any significant changes.

Context: We're trying to fetch a stream of objects from SQL db, and write straight onto a csv file in azure blob storage. As data volume is large 13+GB, we're setting few query hints to fetch 500 objects at a time, disable cacheing also read committed.

We're flushing/Clearing both OpenCSV writer and entity manager every 1500 records.
This was working all good, until we did this migration.

Few code snippets & Profiler Analysis

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
    public void generateFile() {
        try (Stream<MyEntity> supplier = myRepo.getDataStream()) {
            writeOntoFile(ApplicationConstants.REPORT_DIRECTORY, supplier);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            log.error("Error occurred while generating file", ex);
        }
    }
```

```
private <T extends HasId<?>> void writeOntoFile(final String reportDirectory,
                                                     Stream<T> dataStreamSupplier) throws IOException {

        final String blobName = blobName(reportDirectory);

        try (ICSVWriter writer = blobStorageService.getCsvWriterBlobOutputStream(storageContainer, blobName)) {
            log.info("Writing to {} using beantoCsv mapping", reportDirectory);
            StatefulBeanToCsv<T> beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<T>(writer).build();
            final int[] flushCounter = new int[1];
            dataStreamSupplier.forEach(dataRecord -> {
                writeCSV(reportDirectory, dataRecord, beanToCsv);
                flushCounter[0]++;
                if (flushCounter[0] % CLEAR_INTERVAL == 0) {
                    entityManager.clear();
                    entityManagerFactory.getCache().evict(MyEntity.class);
                    try {
                        writer.flush();
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        log.error("Unable to flush the writing stream");
                        throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
                    }
                }
            });
            log.info("Data written in  With Azure Blob file {}", blobName);

        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("Error occurred while processing report {}", reportDirectory, re);
            throw re;
        }
```

Repository Class

```
 @Query("select e from MyEntity e JOIN FETCH e.uuid JOIN FETCH e.sourceTable")
   @QueryHints(value = {
            @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = ApplicationConstants.DATA_FETCH_SIZE),
            @QueryHint(name = HINT_CACHEABLE, value = "false"),
            @QueryHint(name = HINT_READONLY, value = "true")
    })
    Stream<MyEntity> getDataStream();
```

Profiler Log:
[image]
I tried few things such as entityManagerFactory.getCache.evictAll() seems doesn't work.

We're looking to clear these EntityKey objects from Heap. We tried pagination but it's too slow to export such a large volume data.

Comment: Without significant code changes, so things changed, even the smallest change can have a huge impact. Which query hints are you using, some were renamed in either JPA or newer versions of hibernate, as you only included the constant you have defined we can only guess.

Comment: DATA_FETCH_SIZE Constant value is 500. The @QueryHint is now imported from Jakarta instead of Javax. No code changes... few imports did change. Hints are imported from hibernate HINT_FETCH_SIZE, HINT_CACHEABLE etc

Comment: It seems there is a memory leak in your code. This method `writeOntoFile` using a previously created `EntityManager` instance. Please add those parts of code to question where is was created / opened and closed. I assume that instance is open at whole time.

Comment: EntityManager is constructor-injected to the service class. We're using JPA, so entityManager is injected automatically. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: This issue seems to be resolved in Hibernate Version 6.2.0.Final